# Referring to a section of a list as if it were a list itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to take a subsection of a list, that acts as a list, and changes are reflected back to the source list?  For example:

```
x = list(range(10))
y = [some subsection of x]    # What goes here?
y.reverse()
print(x)
```

Desired output, note reversal of elements 3 through 7:

```
[0, 1, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 9]
```

If this is not possible, is there some other facility that will provide similar functionality?

Here is perhaps a better example of the kind of thing I want to do, and as far as I can tell, slice assignment doesn't handle it.  At least, not very elegantly. A recursive quick sort:

```
def QuickSort(x):
    left,right = Partition(x)
    QuickSort(left)
    QuickSort(right)
```

Comment: For the above, you could do `x[3:6] = reversed(x[3:6])`, but I suspect that's not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably *numpy* arrays is what you're looking for. Slicing *numpy* arrays returns a view, not a copy. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing

Comment: Python has `memoryview` for objects that support the buffer interface. For example: `x = array.array('l', range(10)); y = memoryview(x)[3:8]`. Modifying `y` will also change `x`, such as  `y[:] = y[::-1]`. But the view is limited to subscription and slicing, and lists don't support the buffer interface. NumPy arrays with `dtype=object` offer more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this with lists, [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) will often do this.  That is, slices of lists are copies, but slices of numpy arrays are views.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = x[3:6]
y[:] = 1
print y    # [1 1 1]
print x    # [0 1 2 1 1 1 6 7 8 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a modification to `y` directly affect `x`, but you can use slice assignment to update `x` with the values from `y`.  For example:

```
>>> x = list(range(10))
>>> y = x[3:8]
>>> y.reverse()
>>> x[3:8] = y
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 9]
```

Of course you could do this all on one line, `x[3:8] = reversed(x[3:8])`.